# How to print three or four a tables from the Access database in c#

Tags: javascript, c#, php, html

I am unable to print the tables in the databases Access in c#. Please help with finding the right solution

Comment: Have you searched on google?

Comment: Yes but I did not find the required checking!!

Comment: You need to add another layer between Access and C# and for that use ADO. basically, you need to write SQL queries in C# and use a connection string to get connected to your Access DB and then run queries and once you get your results, it is all up to you how to print them using C# functions. So start looking at examples of ADO